# SQL: Iterate a query for 70000 times and sum one field at each iteration

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a text file with session ID's with count as approximately 70000+. 
I have to read every session from that text file and I need to execute the query in database

```
select sessionid,CONT_AMOUNT from RESULT where sessionid in (@text_file);
```

Here CONT_AMOUNT is the field I need to add from every result.

From SQL Developer I can give 1000 sessions at a time but need to execute it more than 70 times.

Is there any better for doing this ?

Comment: load the text file into a table using sqlldr, then join to RESULT table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to create an external table using your file. Refer this link for more details.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i.

Once it's created , you can directly query from the flat file data :

```
SELECT  SUM (CONT_AMOUNT)
  FROM RESULT
 WHERE sessionid IN (SELECT sessionid
                       FROM your_external_tab);
```

Or if you need running `SUM`, you can use.

```
SELECT session_id, SUM (CONT_AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY sessionid)
  FROM RESULT
 WHERE sessionid IN (SELECT sessionid
                       FROM your_external_tab);
```